# How to resolve issue with pagination?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagination

I am facing issue with pagination as its not working correctly. its dropping records.

When we set Limit pagesize its limits to records to search and but i need to limit the page size of the page only and not records. if we paginate it displays same records. means records are not divided e.g 10 records and page size 5 then it should be  5 records per page and 2 pages. but its not working as expected.

Apex class:

```
public with sharing class SearchController{

    public integer PageSize {get;set;}
    public integer PageNumber {get;set;}
    public integer RecordCount {get;set;}
    public List<contactwrapper> objAWList {get;set;}
    private Set<id> selectedContactIds;
    public boolean displayPopup {get; set;}  
    public List<contact> objSelectedContacts {get; set;}
    private String soql {get;set;}  

    public SearchController() {
        PageSize = 10;
        PageNumber = 1;   
        RecordCount = 0;
        selectedContactIds = new Set<id>();
        objAWList = new List<contactwrapper>();
        objSelectedContacts = new List<contact>();

    }


    public void closePopup() {        
        displayPopup = false;    
    }     


    public void showPopup() {  
        setSelectedContacts();      
        displayPopup = true;    
        objSelectedContacts  = GetSelectedcontacts();
    }

    public Integer getSelectedCount(){
        return this.selectedContactIds.size();
    }

    public List<contact> GetSelectedContacts(){    
        List<contact> objConList = [Select Id, Name,Email,Account.Name,Account_Cust__c,Job_Title__c 
                                    From Contact Where ID IN : selectedContactIds];       
        system.debug('objConList :'+objConList);
        return objConList;
    }


    private void setSelectedContacts()
    {
        for(contactwrapper item: objAWList)
        {
            if(item.IsSelected)
            {    
                if(!this.selectedContactIds.contains(item.ContactId))
                {
                    this.selectedContactIds.add(item.ContactId);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(this.selectedContactIds.contains(item.ContactId))
                {
                    this.selectedContactIds.remove(item.ContactId);
                }
            }
        }        
    }

    public integer PageIndex {
        get { return (PageNumber - 1); }
    }    

    public integer PageCount {
        get { return getPageCount(); }
    }

    public integer Offset {
        get { return (PageSize * PageIndex); }
    }


    public void runSearch() {
        objAWList = new List<contactwrapper>();
        try {
                List<Contact> objConList = new List<Contact>(); 
                String contactName = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ContactName');

                if (!contactName.equals('')){
                    soql = 'select firstname, lastname, Name,account.name,Job_Title__c,Account_Cust__c from contact where account.name != null';
                    soql += ' and name LIKE \'%' + contactName + '%\'';
                    soql += ' order by firstName ASC limit '+PageSize +' offset '+Offset;
                    system.debug('soqlfinal::'+soql);
                    objConList = Database.query(soql);
                    RecordCount = objConList.size();

                }else if(contactName.equals('')){
                    RecordCount = objConList.size();
                    objConList.clear();
                }

                 system.debug('objConList---'+objConList);                    
                 if(!objConList.isEmpty()){                         
                     for(Contact Con : objConList){
                            ContactWrapper objAW = new ContactWrapper();
                            objAW.ContactId = Con.Id;
                            objAW.ContactName = Con.Name;
                            objAW.AccountCust= Con.Account_Cust__c ;
                            objAW.JobTitle= Con.Job_Title__c;

                            if(this.selectedContactIds.contains(con.Id)){
                                objAW.IsSelected = true;
                            }
                            else{
                                objAW.IsSelected = false;
                            }
                            objAWList.Add(objAW);
                     }
                 }             

        }
        catch (QueryException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);   

        }
    }

    public integer LNumber {
        get { return RecordCount == 0 ? 0 : (Offset + 1); }
    }

    public integer UNumber {
        get { 
            integer iUNum = ((LNumber + PageSize) - 1);
            return (iUnum > RecordCount) ? RecordCount : iUNum; 
        }
    }

    public boolean AllowMoveNext {
        get{ return ((PageIndex + 1) < PageCount); } } public boolean AllowMovePrev { get{ return (PageIndex > 0); }
    }

    public void Prev() {
        setSelectedContacts();
        PageNumber--;

        if (PageNumber <= 0) { PageNumber = 1; } } public void Next() { setSelectedContacts(); PageNumber++; if (PageNumber > PageCount) {
            PageNumber = PageCount;
        }
    }

    public void Last() {
        setSelectedContacts();
        PageNumber = PageCount; 
    }

    public void First() {
        setSelectedContacts();
        PageNumber = 1;
    }

    private integer getPageCount() {
        integer iPageCount = 1;

        if (RecordCount != 0 && PageSize != 0) {
            iPageCount = (RecordCount/PageSize) + ((Math.mod(RecordCount, PageSize)) > 0 ? 1 : 0);
        }
        return iPageCount;
    }

    public class Contactwrapper
    {
        public Id ContactId {get;set;}
        public String ContactName {get;set;}
        public String AccountCust {get;set;}
        public String JobTitle {get;set;}
        public Boolean IsSelected{get;set;}
        public Contactwrapper()
        {

        }
    }    
}
```

vf code.:

```
<apex:page doctype="html-5.0" controller="SearchController" sidebar="false" readonly="true" cache="false">

<apex:sectionheader title="Contacts"></apex:sectionheader>

<apex:form >
    <apex:pageMessages id="errors" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function doSearch() {
        searchServer(
          document.getElementById("contactName").value);
      }
    </script>

    <apex:actionFunction name="searchServer" action="{!runSearch}" rerender="results,debug,errors">
      <apex:param name="contactName" value="" />
    </apex:actionFunction>

    <apex:pageblock title="Search Contacts" id="idSearchProduct">
        <center>
        <Strong>Search:</strong> <input type="text" id="contactName" onkeyup="doSearch();" class="SearchBox" placeholder="Search"/>
        </center>
    </apex:pageblock>

    <apex:outputpanel id="tstpopup">
    <apex:outputpanel styleclass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}"></apex:outputpanel>
        <apex:outputpanel styleclass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
            <apex:pageblock title="Contacts Preview" >
           <apex:pageblocktable id="pbSelectedAccounts" value="{!objSelectedContacts}" var="cont">
                    <apex:column value="{!cont.Name}" headervalue="Contact Name"></apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!cont.Account_Cust__c}" headervalue="Account Cust#"></apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!cont.Job_Title__c}" headervalue="Job Title"></apex:column>                        
            </apex:pageblocktable><br/>

               <center>
                <apex:commandbutton value="Close" action="{!closePopup}" rerender="tstpopup"></apex:commandbutton>
               </center>
            </apex:pageblock>
        </apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:outputpanel>

    <apex:pageblock title="Search Result" id="results">
        <div align="center" draggable="false" >
        <apex:commandbutton value="Preview Selected Contacts" action="{!showPopup}" rerender="tstpopup"></apex:commandbutton>
        </div><br/>
        <apex:pageblocksection columns="1">
            <apex:facet name="body">
                <apex:outputpanel layout="none">
                    <apex:pageblocktable id="pbAccounts" value="{!objAWList}" var="Con" width="100%">
                        <apex:column width="5%">
                            <apex:facet name="header">Select</apex:facet>
                            <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!Con.IsSelected}"></apex:inputcheckbox>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Contact Name</apex:facet> 
                            <apex:outputlink value="/{!Con.ContactId}">{!Con.ContactName}</apex:outputlink>
                        </apex:column>                           
                        <apex:column value="{!Con.AccountCust}" headervalue="Account Cust#"></apex:column>
                        <apex:column value="{!Con.JobTitle}" headervalue="Job Title"></apex:column>
                    </apex:pageblocktable>
                <apex:outputpanel layout="block" styleclass="listViewport">


        <div class="bottomNav">
        <div class="paginator">
                <apex:panelgrid id="gridPaging" columns="3" width="100%" columnclasses="left, center, right">
                    <apex:panelgroup >
                        <span class="selectorTarget">
                            {!LNumber}-{!UNumber} of {!RecordCount}
                        </span>
                        <span>  </span>
                        <span>
                            Total {!RecordCount} records
                        </span>
                        <span>  </span>
                        <apex:actionstatus id="statusPaging">
                            <apex:facet name="start">
                                <img src="/img/loading.gif" height="14px" width="14px"/>
                            </apex:facet>
                            <apex:facet name="stop">
                                <img src="/img/s.gif" height="14px" width="14px"/>
                            </apex:facet>
                        </apex:actionstatus>                                           
                    </apex:panelgroup>
                    <apex:panelgroup >
                        <span class="prevNextLinks">
                            <span class="prevNext">
                                <apex:commandlink id="linkMoveFirst" status="statusPaging" action="{!First}" rerender="gridPaging, pbAccounts" rendered="{!allowMovePrev}">
                                    <img src="/s.gif" title="First" alt="First" class="first"/>
                                </apex:commandlink>

                                <apex:outputpanel layout="none" rendered="{!NOT(allowMovePrev)}">
                                    <apex:image url="/s.gif" title="First" alt="First" styleclass="firstoff"></apex:image>
                                </apex:outputpanel>
                            </span>

                            <span class="prevNext">
                                <apex:commandlink id="linkMovePrev" title="Previous" status="statusPaging" action="{!Prev}" rerender="gridPaging, pbAccounts" rendered="{!allowMovePrev}">
                                    <img src="/s.gif" title="Previous" alt="Previous" class="prev"/>
                                    <span>Previous</span>
                                </apex:commandlink>
                                <apex:outputpanel layout="none" rendered="{!NOT(allowMovePrev)}">
                                    <apex:image url="/s.gif" title="Previous" alt="Previous" styleclass="prevoff"></apex:image>
                                    <span>Previous</span>
                                </apex:outputpanel>
                            </span>

                            <span class="prevNext">
                                <apex:commandlink id="linkMoveNext" title="Next" status="statusPaging" action="{!Next}" rerender="gridPaging, pbAccounts" rendered="{!allowMoveNext}">
                                    <span>Next</span>
                                    <img src="/s.gif" title="Next" alt="Next" class="next"/>
                                </apex:commandlink>

                                <apex:outputpanel layout="none" rendered="{!NOT(allowMoveNext)}">
                                    <span>Next</span>
                                    <apex:image url="/s.gif" title="Next" alt="Next" styleclass="nextoff"></apex:image>
                                </apex:outputpanel>
                            </span>

                            <span class="prevNext">
                                <apex:commandlink id="linkMoveLast" status="statusPaging" action="{!Last}" rerender="gridPaging, pbAccounts" rendered="{!allowMoveNext}">
                                    <img src="/s.gif" title="Last" alt="Last" class="last"/>
                                </apex:commandlink>

                                <apex:outputpanel layout="none" rendered="{!NOT(allowMoveNext)}">
                                    <apex:image url="/s.gif" title="Last" alt="Last" styleclass="lastoff"></apex:image>
                                </apex:outputpanel>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </apex:panelgroup>
                    <apex:panelgroup >
                        <span class="selectorTarget">
                             Page {!PageNumber} of {!PageCount}
                        </span>
                    </apex:panelgroup>
                </apex:panelgrid> 
             </div>


            </div>


            </apex:outputpanel>
            </apex:outputpanel>
        </apex:facet>
        </apex:pageblocksection>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>



    <style type="text/css">
    .custPopup{
        background-color: #f7f8f9;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        z-index: 9999;
        left: 50%;
        padding:10px;
        position: absolute;         
        width: 700px;
        margin-left: -320px;
        top:100px;
        border-color:#1797C0; 
    }
    .popupBackground{
        background-color: #4286f4;
        opacity: 0.10;
        filter: alpha(opacity = 20);
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 9998;

    }
    .SearchBox
    {
       -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border:solid 1px #4286f4;
        padding:5px;
        width: 30%;
        outline: none;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: Define clearly what's not working. Also post your Visualforce code

Comment: Hry rahul, described the issue and posted vf code also

Comment: Why are you not using `StandardSetController` here?

Comment: I want to keep state whithin paging so, if we select records it would not cuase issue of deselected automatically